# kivy : missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'

Tags: python, kivy, typeerror, instance

just started learning kivy
Whats wrong with the code? it gives the error
Exception has occurred: TypeError
new_tbox() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'

```
class grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.left_side = GridLayout()
        self.left_side.cols = 1
        self.left_side.add_widget(Label(text = "Add the words you want to the dictionary! : "))
        self.text_boxes = GridLayout()
        self.text_boxes.cols = 1
        self.text_boxes.add_widget(TextInput(multiline = False))
        self.text_boxes.add_widget(TextInput(multiline = False))
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(self.left_side)
        self.add_widget(self.text_boxes)
        self.text_add = Button(text = "add a new word", font_size = 30) 
        self.add_widget(self.text_add)
        self.text_add.bind(on_press = self.new_tbox)

def new_tbox(self, instance):
    self.text_boxes.add_widget(TextInput(multiline = False))
class first_app(App):
    def build(self):
        return grid()
first_app().run()
```

Comment: Is your `new_tbox()` method a member of a class?

Comment: Your posted code seems to have indentation problems. Please edit your post to show correct indentation.

Comment: ugh, really thank you, my bad!

Comment: again, noticed that right now, fixed

Comment: If the indentation is now correct, then `new_tbox()` is not a member of the `grid` class, and should not have a `self` argument. Also `self.text_add.bind(on_press = self.new_tbox)` will not work if `new_tbox()` is not a member of class `grid`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @john-anderson
`new_tbox()` wasn't a part of the class
my bad!